# WordPress: Post-specific email address to append/prepend contents to the post

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins

Does anyone know of a plugin or method to update a specific post by sending an email to a specific post-related email address? For example:

- Create a post titled Foo.
- An obfuscated email address is created: enoi34y4he2kg4@domain.com
- Anything emailed to that address is appended or prepended to the post.

This is different than the current "Email to Wordpress" functionality that exists, in that the emails do not create new posts. They just add to an existing post.

**tl;dr**: Looking for Email -> Wordpress Live Blogging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot find a preexisting solution, you could consider checking out a WordPress plugin called [Postie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/) and modifying its source. You will likely need to do some significant modification, but it might give you a starting point as to how a plugin accomplishes email interaction as opposed to basing it off of the WordPress core code.

Comment: I've actually got that open right now, was reading about it, and thought "oh, maybe SO has a better solution." So, if SO fails me, you get the answer!